# What is a valid Facebook Open Graph Action Link URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When you go to your application, Open Graph, Action Types, click on an action type, Advanced Options at the bottom, and try adding an action link. What's a valid URL?

Bonus: How do you add more than one action link?

Comment: 1. RTFM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#howto-actionlinks, 2. You don’t, one action link is the maximum possible.

Comment: TFM is outdated! Look at the screenshots, they don't match the current interface and the instructions describe what you need to do in the old interface. The instructions clearly state that you need to fill by the Linked Action and the Action Link URL. In the current interface as I finally figured out, if you fill the Linked Action field you shouldn't and cannot fill the Action Link URL field.

Thanks for answering the bonus question. Have an up vote.